# Python3 импорт всех .py файлов из папки

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, импорт

У меня имеется много функций находящихся в разных файлах. Можно ли каким-то образом создать папку и, импортировав только эту папку, обращаться к этим функциям? К примеру, имеются функции A B C D E F. Я их складываю в папку Fun. Псевдокод:

```
import Fun
A()
B()
C()
...
```

Единственное решение, которое я находил это создать ещё один .py файл и туда ручками импортировать все функции по одной. Есть ли какой-то элегантный способ решения?

Comment: Как вы функции "складываете" в директорию?

Comment: @dIm0n файлы с функциями помещаю в директорию. К примеру, /WorkDirectory/Fun/A.py. В WorkDirectory находится исполняемый файл python с точкой входа. Fun - место нахождения файлов с функциями.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

Answer (score 2):

В директорию `Fun` добавляете файл `__init__.py` с таким содержимым:

```
from .A import A
from .B import B
from .C import C
...
from .Z import Z
```

В основном файле:

```
from Fun import *

A()
B()
C()
```

Либо без `__init__.py` вызываете функции по полному "пути":

```
import Fun

Fun.A.A()
Fun.B.B()
Fun.C.C()
```